# How To Move A Link Image Lower

Tags: html, css, blogger

I would like to move an image slightly lower so that the text alongside the image is in the middle and everything looks aligned. I have tried to achieve this look by adding padding and margin values but to no avail. The URL to my blog is as follows : http://www.blankesque.com

The html coding for the image is as follows :

```
<b:if cond='data:newerPageUrl'>
  <span id='blog-pager-newer-link'>
  <a class='blog-pager-newer-link' expr:href='data:newerPageUrl' expr:id='data:widget.instanceId + &quot;_blog-pager-newer-link&quot;' expr:title='data:newerPageTitle'>Next  <img border='0' height='20px' src='http://i1379.photobucket.com/albums/ah140/mynamesiram/Mobile%20Uploads/0C6ACBDC-DFDC-45F6-9811-E5A8CDFCA8B6_zpsxowcscnl.jpg' width='20px'/></a>
  </span>
</b:if>

<b:if cond='data:olderPageUrl'>
  <span id='blog-pager-older-link'>
  <a class='blog-pager-older-link' expr:href='data:olderPageUrl' expr:id='data:widget.instanceId + &quot;_blog-pager-older-link&quot;' expr:title='data:olderPageTitle'><img border='0' height='20px' src='http://i1379.photobucket.com/albums/ah140/mynamesiram/Mobile%20Uploads/75D8D238-DBEE-440E-AED5-525720876C13_zpsvhhmbezy.jpg' width='20px'/>  Previous</a>
  </span>
</b:if>
```

**CSS:**

```
#blog-pager-newer-link {
    float:right;
    margin: 3% 0 3% 0;
}
#blog-pager-older-link {
    float: left;
    margin: 3% 0 3% 0;
}
.blog-pager-older-link {
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family: 'karla', arial;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 0.09em;
    color: #333333;
    font-weight: normal!important;
}
.blog-pager-newer-link {
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family: 'karla', arial;
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: 0.09em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #333333;
    font-weight: normal!important;
}
```

Comment: Add screen shot, then tag me.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to you CSS:

```
a img{
    margin-top:2px;
}
```

[image]

Note that it is better to give this anchor `a` or this `img` a unique identifier `id` so that this CSS won't affect *all* `img` elements wrapped in anchors `a` in your webpage while trying to address *only* this image, something like:

```
a#lil-icon img
```

Also note that it is wrong to wrap an `li` with a `div`

```
<ul>
  <div class="homeicon">
    <li>
      <a href="http://www.blankesque.com"><!-- img --></a>
    </li>
  </div>
  <li><a href="http://www.blankesque.com/p/aboutblankesque.html">About</a>      </li>

  <!-- the rest of your li's -->
</ul>
```

From [validator.w3.org](https://validator.w3.org/nu/) while validating this piece of code:

> Error: Element div not allowed as child of element ul in this context.

To fix it just put the `.homeicon` on the `li`, change it into this:

```
<ul>
    <li class="homeicon">
        <a href="http://www.blankesque.com"><!-- img --></a>
    </li>

    <li><a href="http://www.blankesque.com/p/aboutblankesque.html">About</a></li>
      <!-- the rest of your li's -->
</ul>
```

Comment: Apologies I didn't explain well enough. I was referring to the image I have along with my "previous" and "next" text that appears at the end of a post to direct the reader to the last or next post. I have tried this coding but even this hasn't worked for me. .blog-pager-older-link a img { padding-top: 2px!important; }

Answer (score 0):

You mean the little image top left, yes?

You already have `position: relative;` for that image, so just add `bottom: -2px;` to the image rule (or whatever distance you prefer):

```
.homeicon a img {
    border: medium none;
    position: relative;
    bottom: -2px;
}
```

Comment: Apologies I didn't explain well enough. I was referring to the image I have along with my "previous" and "next" text that appears at the end of a post to direct the reader to the last or next post. I have tried this coding but even this hasn't worked for me. .blog-pager-older-link a img { padding-top: 2px!important; }